# application passwords unreadable in mfc

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How to make application passwords unreadable during transmission and storage,
using strong cryptography based on approved standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great implementation for the most used algorithms (MD2, MD4, SHA1, ...) here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/chash.aspx

I hope it helps.